# How do I create a pivot table with weighted averages from a table in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, pivot-table, powerbi-desktop, unpivot

I have data in the following format:

| Building | Tenant | Type | Floor | Sq Ft | Rent | Term Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Example Way | Jeff | Renewal | 5 | 100 | 100 | 6 |
| 47 Fake Street | Tom | New | 3 | 500 | 200 | 12 |

I need to create a visualisation in PowerBI that displays a pivot table of attribute by tenant, with a weighted averages (by square foot) column, like this:

|  | Jeff | Tom | Weighted Average (by Sq Ft) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Building | 1 Example Way | 47 Fake Street | - |
| Type | Renewal | New | - |
| Floor | 5 | 3 | - |
| Sq Ft | 100 | 500 | 433.3333333 |
| Rent | 100 | 200 | 183.3333333 |
| Term Length (months) | 6 | 12 | 11 |

I have unpivoted the original data, like this:

| Tenant | Attribute | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jeff | Building | 1 Example Way |
| Jeff | Type | Renewal |
| Jeff | Floor | 5 |
| Jeff | Sq Ft | 100 |
| Jeff | Rent | 100 |
| Jeff | Term Length (months) | 6 |
| Tom | Building | 47 Fake Street |
| Tom | Type | New |
| Tom | Floor | 3 |
| Tom | Sq Ft | 500 |
| Tom | Rent | 200 |
| Tom | Term Length (months) | 12 |

I can almost create what I need from the unpivoted data using a matrix (as below), but I can't calculate the weighted averages column from that matrix.

|  | Jeff | Tom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Building | 1 Example Way | 47 Fake Street |
| Type | Renewal | New |
| Floor | 5 | 3 |
| Sq Ft | 100 | 500 |
| Rent | 100 | 200 |
| Term Length (months) | 6 | 12 |

I can also create a table with my attributes as headers (instead of in a column). This displays the right values and lets me calculate weighted averages (as below).

|  | Building | Type | Floor | Sq Ft | Rent | Term Length (months) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jeff | 1 Example Way | Renewal | 5 | 100 | 100 | 6 |
| Tom | 47 Fake Street | New | 3 | 500 | 200 | 12 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Weighted Average (by Sq Ft) | - | - | - | 433.3333333 | 183.3333333 | 11 |

However, it's important that these values are displayed vertically instead of horizontally. This is pretty straightforward in Excel, but I can't figure out how to do it in PowerBI. I hope this is clear. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: What is a "weighted average" in your world?

Comment: @Peter I should have been clearer - I'm looking for an average, across the tenants, of the numeric columns (square foot, rent, term length) weighted by square foot